# Multicasting video server

Tags: video, streaming, multicast

I am able to multicast packets, i.e. sending files or chatting over a multicast connection (that's asynchronous), and I'd like to multicast streaming videos from my servers, but I don't know where to start server side and client side too. Any suggestion ? thanks !!